# CSS3 rotate around a fixed point

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

I cannot work out why this carousel rotates around a floating point.

I wonder if anyone could shed some light on this.

There's a sass loop hidden in there which should position and rotate each individual pane, this should rotate around the transform-origin of a central box, which doesn't appear to move sideways.

Any pointers would be much obliged!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fjKtv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the #carousel element set to a width of 200px.

Then this element has li's that are set to a width of 50%.

If you don't set anything else, this li are left aligned in the #carousel. This left alignment makes the full rotation be off-axis.

You can fix it setting margin to auto, for instance

```
.cssanimations.csstransforms3d #carousel li {
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

(only the last property added )